# Split CSV file according to value in a column, but only keep 1 column and save as TXT

Tags: csv, awk

I have a two column spreadsheet (saved in CSV format) that is like this:

```
COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2
innovation,3-Entrepreneurship
countless,
innocent,2-Police
toilet handle,2-Bathroom
née dresses,3-Companies
odorless,2-Sense of Smell
old ideas,3-Entrepreneurship
new income streams,3-Entrepreneurship
Zoë’s food store,3-Companies
many,
crime,2-Police
bath room,2-Bathroom
ring,
móvíl résumés,3-Companies
musty smell,2-Sense of Smell
good publicity guru,3-Entrepreneurship
Señor,3-Companies
```

The full spreadsheet is 6000 rows (saved in CSV format, with commas used to separate the two columns). It has more than the Column 2 categories that are listed here.

As shown, some of the column 1 entries consists of two- or three- words separated by a space. They also make use of apostrophes and accented characters (these appear in multiple categories and not just the category titled `3-Companies`).

You can download a sample of the full spreadsheet [here](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_157).

I would like to split the CSV file up in to separate TXT files by the values in column 2. The separate files will no longer be a spreadsheet table, but just a list of words.

**E.g. after split**

**In file *3-Entrepreneurship.txt***

```
innovation
old ideas
new income streams
good publicity guru
```

**In file *2-Bathroom.txt***

```
toilet handle
bath room
```

**In file *2-Police.txt***

```
innocent
crime
```

**In file *2-Sense of Smell.txt***

```
odorless
musty smell
```

**In file *3-Companies.txt***

```
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
móvíl résumés
Señor
```

This is only a sample. The full file has more than 5 categories (in column 2), so there will be more than 5 post-split files.

---

### Here is my code so far:

```
awk -F "," '{print $0 >> ($2 ".txt"); close($2 ".txt")}' test.csv
```

It works, but there are a few issues:

1. The file names are printed out with question marks at the end.
   E.g. `2-Police?.txt` `3-Entrepreneurship?.txt`
2. The files print out with two columns.

For example inside of **3-Entrepreneurship.txt** it has the following data:

```
innovation  3-Entrepreneurship
ideas       3-Entrepreneurship
income      3-Entrepreneurship
publicity   3-Entrepreneurship
```

Comment: You should print the first field, not the whole line: `print $1 >>`. Your second issue is probably due to DOS line ending ("\r\n") in the input file. You may want to call `awk` with `awk -v RS='\r\n'`

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin that works, but it adds a blank row before every row. Here is the full code I am using `awk -v RS='\r\n' -F "," '{print $1 >> ($2 ".csv"); close($2 ".csv")}' test1.csv`

Comment: I don't know. Your awk call works fine on my box. But beware that the lines with only one field will be collected in a file named `.csv`.

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin I am using Mac OS 10.14.6 if that makes a difference?

Comment: You may try to call awk with `awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r'`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Whoops, I just realized, I am supposed to output the files as TXT format (as a list of lines), rather than CSV, so my code would be `awk -v RS='\r\n' -F "," '{print $1 >> ($2 ".txt"); close($2 ".txt")}' test1.csv` (which works, it just puts a blank row before each file. When I try `awk -v RS='\r\n' ORS='\r -F "," '{print $1 >> ($2 ".txt"); close($2 ".txt")}' test1.csv`, it says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(`

Comment: You have typos in the command line. It should have been `awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r'`...

Comment: @M.NejatAydin using more than 1 char in the RS is undefined behavipr per POSIX so setting `RS='\r\n'` will do what you want in GNU awk and maybe some others but in others still it'll behave as if you wrote `RS='\r'` which is probably why the OP is seeing blank lines before each record, it's the `\n` that was supposed to be at the end of each line now being put at the start of the next line.

Comment: @big_smile wrt `I am using Mac OS 10.14.6 if that makes a difference` yes it does. The default awk on MacOS is BSD awk and it only expects single-char RS values and truncates any multi-char RS to the first char and so will treat `RS='\r\n'` as if you wrote `RS='\r'`. If you install GNU awk instead then you can use multi-char RS and a ton of other very useful extensions.

Comment: wrt `-F ","` - the input file in your question has no commas in it so telling awk that your input is comma-separated is just going to break your script.

Comment: @Ed Morton is there any way I can use `RS='\r\n'` on Mac without needing to install new things? Thanks! Also, the input file is in CSV format, so it does have commas. I will update the OP to make that clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton @M.NejatAydin Here is the final code so far `awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r' -F "," '{print $1 >> ($2 ".txt"); close($2 ".txt")}' test1.csv` It works fine, it just puts a blank line above the row (which I guess is because I am using Mac OS). In the chat (at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220042/discussion-between-big-smile-and-m-nejat-aydin) it was suggest the input file could be the problem, so I have uploaded the input file here if that might shed any light: http://www.filedropper.com/sample_150

Comment: wrt "is there any way" - yes, just use [the script I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478213/1745001). The `sub(/\r$/,"")` simply removes the `\r` at the end of each line and so the default RS works as-is. Again, setting `RS='\r\n'` is the wrong thing to do on MacOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tail -n +2 file |
sort -t',' -k2 |
awk -F',' '$2~/^[[:space:]]*$/{next} {sub(/\r$/,"")} $2!=prev{close(out); out=$2".txt"; prev=$2} {print $1 > out}'
```

We sort the data first for efficiency so that awk doesn't have to keep opening/closing files line by line but instead only does that once per unique $2 value.

Here's the script working:

```
$ ls
file

$ cat file
COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2
innovation,3-Entrepreneurship
countless,
innocent,2-Police
toilet handle,2-Bathroom
née dresses,3-Companies
odorless,2-Sense of Smell
old ideas,3-Entrepreneurship
new income streams,3-Entrepreneurship
Zoë’s food store,3-Companies
many,
crime,2-Police
bath room,2-Bathroom
ring,
móvíl résumés,3-Companies
musty smell,2-Sense of Smell
good publicity guru,3-Entrepreneurship
Señor,3-Companies
```

.

```
$ tail -n +2 file | sort -t',' -k2 | awk -F',' '$2~/^[[:space:]]*$/{next} {sub(/\r$/,"")} $2!=prev{close(out); out=$2".txt"; prev=$2} {print $1 > out}'
```

.

```
$ ls
 2-Bathroom.txt   2-Police.txt  '2-Sense of Smell.txt'   3-Companies.txt   3-Entrepreneurship.txt   file

$ head -n 50 *.txt
==> 2-Bathroom.txt <==
bath room
toilet handle

==> 2-Police.txt <==
crime
innocent

==> 2-Sense of Smell.txt <==
musty smell
odorless

==> 3-Companies.txt <==
móvíl résumés
née dresses
Señor
Zoë’s food store

==> 3-Entrepreneurship.txt <==
good publicity guru
innovation
new income streams
old ideas
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated the opening post. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: Thanks this is great! I notice that it adds a blank line to the end of every file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that as you can see in the `head` output in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

First, it seems that the words without a value in column 2 should not be written to a file. If so, add a test to your action. The test can be just `$2` which will skip the action inside the `{ ... }` if `$2` is blank.

Second, if you want only the word, write only col 1 to the file -- not the entire line in `$0`

With your example, which is not `,` delimited, you can do:

```
awk '$2 {print $1 >> ($2 ".txt"); close($2 ".txt")}' file
```

Be sure to delete the `.txt` files or run in an empty directory since this appends the files if they already exist.

Produces:

```
2-Bathroom.txt:
toilet
bath

2-Police.txt:
innocent
crime

2-Sense.txt:
odorless
musty

3-Entrepreneurship.txt:
innovation
ideas
income
publicity
```

Comment: This sort of works, except `,3-Entrepreneurship.txt` is split into two files. The first file contains "innovation", "ideas" and "income", while the second file (`,3-Entrepreneurship?.txt`) contains only "publicity". Also, all file names have a comma before them.