# MacOS Terminal: Split CSV file by column 1 value

Tags: macos, csv, awk

I have a two column spreadsheet (saved in CSV format) that is like this:

```
COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2
3-Entrepreneurship,"innovation, daily"
,countless
2-Police/Enforcement,"innocent, protect"
2-Bathroom:home room,toilet handle
3-Companies,née dresses
2-Sense of Smell,odorless
3-Entrepreneurship,old ideas
3-Entrepreneurship,¡new income streams!
3-Companies,Zoë’s food store
,many
2-Police/Enforcement,crime
2-Bathroom:home room,bath room
,ring
3-Companies,móvíl résumés
2-Sense of Smell,musty smell
3-Entrepreneurship,good publicity guru!
3-Companies,Señor
```

[image]

The full spreadsheet is 1000 rows (saved in CSV format, with commas used to separate the two columns). It has more than the Column 1 categories that are listed here.

As shown, some of the column 2 entries consists of two- or three- words separated by a space. They also make use of commas, apostrophes and accented characters (these appear in multiple categories and not just the category titled 3-Companies).

I would like to split the CSV file up in to separate TXT files by the values in column 1. The separate files will no longer be a spreadsheet table, but just a list of words.

E.g. after split

***In file 3-Entrepreneurship.txt***

```
3-Entrepreneurship
innovation, daily
old ideas
¡new income streams!
good publicity guru!
```

***In file 2-Bathroom:home room.txt***

```
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
```

***In file 2-Police/Enforcement.txt***

```
2-Police/Enforcement
innocent, protect
crime
```

***In file 2-Sense of Smell.txt***

```
2-Sense of Smell
odorless
musty smell
```

***In file 3-Companies.txt***

```
3-Companies
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
móvíl résumés
Señor
```

This is only a sample. The full file has more than 5 categories (in column 2), so there will be more than 5 post-split files.

---

**Environment**
I am using terminal in MacOS 12.6.9.
Ideally, I would like to copy and paste a single line of code and have it act on the CSV file in the directory that the terminal is active in (so I don't have to hard code in the name of the file into the code.)

---

**Initial attempts**

I actually asked a different variation of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470440/split-csv-file-according-to-value-in-a-column-but-only-keep-1-column-and-save-a/).
In that version, column 2 (instead of Column 1) was used to make the split. That version also did NOT put the category as the top line of every split TXT file.

I've tried modifying it, as follows:

```
tail -n +2 *.csv | sort -t',' -k2 | awk -F',' '$2~/^[[:space:]]*$/{next} {sub(/\x0d$/,"")} $2!=prev{close(out); out=$2".txt"; prev=$2} {print $1 > out}'
```

However, although it splits by column 1 and puts the category name at the top, it omits all the contents of category 2 and instead splits out all the category 2 values as separate files.

Please note: I am not bound to this code. Any solution that works in MacOS 12.6.9 is fine.

Comment: The `/` is not a legal character for a filename in Unix or MacOS. Therefor your example filename of `2-Police/Enforcement` would need to be some other character.

Comment: @dawg yeah, I realized after commenting that I was misreading the input and what I thought was a newline after quotes within a field was actually the start of the next record with an empty first field so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Regarding "I would like to copy and paste a single line of code" - you can cram almost any program into a single line if you like but don't ask for that in your question as it discourages people from answering as it means you favor brevity over robustness, efficiency, clarity, portability and anything else that actually matters in software. Get a good answer then cram it into one line if you like but you'd be far better off saving it as a script and then calling that script as your "one liner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk regardless of how many output files will be generated and without storing all of the input in memory and it'll handle escaped double quotes in the input correctly (e.g. it'll convert `a,"foo""bar",b` to `a,foo"bar,b` instead of `a,foo""bar,b`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR > 1 {
    pos = index($0,",")
    tag = substr($0,1,pos-1)    # tag is everything before first ,
    val = substr($0,pos+1)      # val[ue] is everything after it

    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)        # strip field-enclosing quotes
    gsub(/""/,"\"",val)         # de-escape CSV quotes so "" -> "

    out = (tag == "" ? prevTag : tag ) ".txt"
    gsub("/","_",out)           # file names cannot contain / so map to _

    if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
        print tag > out
    }
    print val >> out
    close(out)                  # necessary to avoid "too many open files"

    prevTag = tag
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
```

```
$ head *.txt
==> 2-Bathroom:home room.txt <==
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
ring

==> 2-Police_Enforcement.txt <==
2-Police/Enforcement
innocent, protect
crime

==> 2-Sense of Smell.txt <==
2-Sense of Smell
odorless
musty smell

==> 3-Companies.txt <==
3-Companies
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
many
móvíl résumés
Señor

==> 3-Entrepreneurship.txt <==
3-Entrepreneurship
innovation, daily
countless
old ideas
¡new income streams!
good publicity guru!
```

Alternatively you could use the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) for improved efficiency since it wouldn't require opening/closing the output file on every write, just once per tag:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v OFS=',' '
    NR > 1 {
        pos = index($0,",")
        tag = substr($0,1,pos-1)    # tag is everything before first ,
        val = substr($0,pos+1)      # val[ue] is everything after it

        print NR, (tag == "" ? prevTag : tag), val
        prevTag = tag
    }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -t',' -k2,2 -k1,1n |
awk -F',' '
    $2 != prevTag {
        close(out)
        out = $2 ".txt"
        gsub("/","_",out)       # file names cannot contain / so map to _
        print $2 > out
        prevTag = $2
    }
    {
        sub(/[^,]+,[^,]+,/,"")  # remove the NR and tag
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"")        # strip field-enclosing quotes
        gsub(/""/,"\"")         # de-escape CSV quotes so "" -> "
        print > out
    }
'
```

You'd call that as `./tst.sh file.csv`.

A benefit to that DSU script vs storing all of the input in awk and then processing it in the `END` section is that with the above only `sort` needs to operate on the whole of the input at once, not `awk`, and `sort` uses demand paging etc. to be able to handle arbitrarily large input files.

Comment: great thnx dear Ed ++!

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
#NR==1 { next }                                                 # uncomment this line if the file *DOES* include the header record "COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2"
       { pos = index($0,",")                                    # find location of first comma

         cat = substr($0,1,pos-1)                               # extract the category
         gsub(/\//,":",cat)                                     # replace "/" with ":" (unix/linux filenames cannot include "/")
         if (! cat) cat = prevcat                               # if cat is empty/blank then use prevcat

         words = substr($0,pos+1)                               # extract the words
         gsub(/^"|"$/,"",words)                                 # strip any leading/trailing double quote

         cats[cat] = (cats[cat] ? cats[cat] : cat) ORS words    # update our categories array (cats[]) with our new data; if cats[cat] is empty (ie, this is a new array entry) then start by adding our cat to the list

         prevcat = cat                                          # update previous cat
       }

END    { for (cat in cats) {                                    # loop through list of categories (ie, the indexes of the cats[] array)
             outfile = cat ".txt"                               # create output file name
             print cats[cat] > outfile                          # print array entry to output file
             close (outfile)                                    # close the output file
         }
       }
' full.csv
```

**NOTE:** this solution replaces all of OP's current `tail | sort | awk` code

This generates:

```
$ head -20 [0-9]*.txt
==> 2-Bathroom:home room.txt <==
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
ring

==> 2-Police:Enforcement.txt <==
2-Police:Enforcement
innocent, protect
crime

==> 2-Sense of Smell.txt <==
2-Sense of Smell
odorless
musty smell

==> 3-Companies.txt <==
3-Companies
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
many
móvíl résumés
Señor

==> 3-Entrepreneurship.txt <==
3-Entrepreneurship
innovation, daily
countless
old ideas
¡new income streams!
good publicity guru!
```

Comment: nice method, great job ++, Is this file also necessary to be created? `COLUMN 1.txt`

Comment: @Freeman it's not clear (to me) from the question if `COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2` is actually in the file (it shows up in the textual content but not in the image); if this line really does exist in the file then see the comment for the first line of my script (`#NR==1 {next}`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new { |x, key| x[key] = [] }; last_col_1=""}
$<.each_line.with_index{|line,i|
    next if i==0
    lc=CSV.parse(line).flatten
    if lc[0].nil? then col_1=last_col_1 else col_1=lc[0] end
    last_col_1=col_1
    h[col_1] << lc[1]
}
h.each{|k,v| File.open("#{k.gsub(/\//,":")}.txt", "w"){|f| f.write "#{k}\n#{v.join("\n")}"} }
' your_file
```

(Note, the character `/` replaced in the filename with `:` in the example input to produce `2-Police:Enforcement.txt` since `2-Police/Enforcement.txt` is an illegal filename.)

Produces:

```
% head *.txt
==> 2-Bathroom:home room.txt <==
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
ring
==> 2-Police:Enforcement.txt <==
2-Police/Enforcement
innocent, protect
crime
==> 2-Sense of Smell.txt <==
2-Sense of Smell
odorless
musty smell
==> 3-Companies.txt <==
3-Companies
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
many
móvíl résumés
Señor
==> 3-Entrepreneurship.txt <==
3-Entrepreneurship
innovation, daily
countless
old ideas
¡new income streams!
good publicity guru!
```

Comment: I've got this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
 4: from -e:9:in `<main>'
 3: from -e:9:in `each'
 2: from -e:9:in `block in <main>'
 1: from -e:9:in `open'
-e:9:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 2-Police/Enforcement.txt (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: That is because `/` is  illegal in a filename. I fixed the Ruby to fix this... Try the new version

Comment: good job ++, I liked ruby 

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this with Perl :

```
perl -F, -lane 'if ($. != 1) { $pos = index($_, ","); $cat = substr($_, 0, $pos); $cat =~ s/\//:/g; $cat = $prevcat if $cat eq ""; $words = substr($_, $pos+1); $words =~ s/^"|"$//g; $cats{$cat} = ($cats{$cat} ? $cats{$cat} : $cat) . "\n" . $words; $prevcat = $cat; } END { while (($cat, $words) = each %cats) { open(my $fh, ">", "$cat.txt") or die "Cannot open $cat.txt: $!"; print $fh $words; close($fh); } }' your_data.csv
```

Generated files :

```
$ ls -1 *.txt
2-Bathroom:home room.txt
2-Police:Enforcement.txt
2-Sense of Smell.txt
3-Companies.txt
3-Entrepreneurship.txt
```

Output:

```
$ head *.txt
==> 2-Bathroom:home room.txt <==
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
ring

==> 2-Police:Enforcement.txt <==
2-Police:Enforcement
innocent, protect
crime

==> 2-Sense of Smell.txt <==
2-Sense of Smell
odorless
musty smell

==> 3-Companies.txt <==
3-Companies
née dresses
Zoë’s food store
many
móvíl résumés
Señor

==> 3-Entrepreneurship.txt <==
3-Entrepreneurship
innovation, daily
countless
old ideas
¡new income streams!
good publicity guru!
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness you could do this with plain `bash` (as you have only 1000 rows performance should not be an issue). Note that, different from other awk-based answers, this really creates the files you want, even in a subdirectory (e.g., `2-Police/Enforcement.txt`). And as the other answers it will not work if you have multi-line records in your input CSV. And if your second line has an empty first field the text file that will be created is `.txt`. Put the following in a file (e.g., `~/bin/csv2txt`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tail -n+2 "$1" | while IFS=, read -r tmp b; do
  a="${tmp:-$a}"
  [[ "$a" == */* ]] && mkdir -p "${a%/*}"
  [[ -f "$a.txt" ]] || printf '%s\n' "$a" > "$a.txt"
  b="${b#\"}"
  printf '%s\n' "${b%\"}" >> "$a.txt"
done
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/csv2txt
```

And then:

```
~/bin/csv2txt file.csv
```

Or, if you already have `~/bin` in your `PATH`:

```
csv2txt file.csv
```

Explanations:

- `tail -n+2 "$1" | while IFS=, read -r tmp b; do`: We use `tail` to remove the first line of your CSV file and pipe the others to a `while` loop with Input Field Separator (`IFS`) set to comma. For each line we store the first field (before the first comma) in `tmp` and the rest of the line (after the first comma) in `b`. We use the `-r` option of `read` to not allow backslashes to escape any characters.
- `a="${tmp:-$a}"`: If `tmp` is not empty we assign it to `a`, else (for example on your 3rd line `,countless`) we let `a` unmodified.
- `[[ "$a" == */* ]] && mkdir -p "${a%/*}"`: If `a` contains a slash (e.g., `2-Police/Enforcement`) we create the corresponding directory.
- `[[ -f "$a.txt" ]] || printf '%s\n' "$a" > "$a.txt"`: If the target text file (`"$a.txt"`) does not exist yet we print `$a` in it.
- `b="${b#\"}"`: We remove any leading `"` from `b`.
- `printf '%s\n' "${b%\"}" >> "$a.txt"`: We remove any trailing `"` from `b` and append its value to the target text file.

Comment: Please also provide a method that does not require to be inside a folder. thnx

Comment: What do you mean? You are always inside a folder, the current one.

Comment: And also your first line not consist of filename !

Comment: Thus the subshell and `tail -n+2` to skip the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Python can correctly handle your CSV data.  The program below uses a dictionary (map) to store each value (col2) in a list that is keyed to the last category (col1) that was seen.  This last-seen approach allows a value with a missing category to be associated with the last category (above it):

```py
import csv

category_values: dict[str, list[str]] = {}

with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    category = ""
    for row in reader:
        _category, value = row[0], row[1]

        if _category != "" and _category != category:
            category = _category

        if category not in category_values:
            category_values[category] = []

        category_values[category].append(value)
```

We can check the dictionary with two sets of loops:

```py
for category, values in category_values.items():
    print(category)
    for value in values:
        print(f"  {value}")
```

and I get:

```
3-Entrepreneurship
  innovation, daily
  countless
  old ideas
  ¡new income streams!
  good publicity guru!
2-Police/Enforcement
  innocent, protect
  crime
2-Bathroom:home room
  toilet handle
  bath room
  ring
3-Companies
  née dresses
  Zoë’s food store
  many
  móvíl résumés
  Señor
2-Sense of Smell
  odorless
  musty smell
```

Then use a similar set of loops to write the category-values to their own files.  I do some basic filename sanitizing based on the category:

```py
for category, values in category_values.items():
    fname = category.replace("/", "-").replace(":", "-").replace("\\", "-")
    with open(f"output-{fname}.txt", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(category + "\n")
        for value in values:
            f.write(value + "\n")
```

and I get a list of files like:

```
output-2-Bathroom-home room.txt
output-2-Police-Enforcement.txt
output-2-Sense of Smell.txt
output-3-Companies.txt
output-3-Entrepreneurship.txt
```

output-2-Bathroom-home room.txt looks like:

```
2-Bathroom:home room
toilet handle
bath room
ring
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle quoted values which might in turn contain escaped quotes etc, you want a language with a proper CSV parser.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

with open('input.csv') as csvin:
    for row in csv.reader(csvin):
        with open(row[0], 'a') as txtout:
            txtout.write(row[1] + '\n')
```

Here is a somewhat more adorned version with more corner cases covered. I assume the example with the empty cell in the first column should be skipped, and that labels with slashes in them should result in subdirectories.

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

with open('input.csv') as csvin:
    # skip header
    reader = csv.reader(csvin)
    reader.__next__()
    for row in reader:
        if row[0]:
            if '/' in row[0]:
                Path(row[0]).parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            with open(row[0] + '.txt', 'a+') as txtout:
                txtout.write(row[1] + '\n')
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/7akFvw

If you want the first line to contain a header, that will complicate the code somewhat (you need to check whether the file already exists or not) but I consider the lack of the header a feature, not a bug.

If you really need to optimize this for speed, you should keep open as many file handles as possible, but back off if you open more than the OS allows (typically on the order of 20). Closing and immediately reopening a file tends to get a lot slower.

Comment: I've got this error : `File "1.py", line 5
    with open('1.csv') as csvin
                               ^
SyntaxError: expected ':'`

Comment: Sorry about that; updated. Unfortunately, I'm not in a place where I can test this right now.

Comment: Again I've got this error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(row[0], 'a') as csvout:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`

Comment: To be honest, your code has a lot of work to do because, for example, instead of generating a file, a folder is created. Also, you didn't remove the double quotation marks, and so on.

Comment: The CSV reader removes _only the right_ quote marks. See the demo; maybe fork it and try with more complex CSV files (quoted strings containing quoted strings?)